# HPC ssh "connection closed by remote host"

Tags: ssh

My HPC installed LSF job scheduler.

I logon the login node (I use xshell) and using interactive job submission command

```
bsub -Is csh
```

Thus, I entered one of the HPC node, for example `c01` node

Then I want to enter another node, for example `c02`, so I use

```
ssh c02
```

I successfully entered `c02` node. But after several minutes, the connection is closed. The message is

```
Connection to c02 closed by remote host. 
Connection to c02 closed.
```

**So how to maintain this connection?**

The following message is generated when using `ssh -vvv c02`

```
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 2925
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 4 w 5 e 6 c -1
Connection to c02 closed by remote host.
Connection to c02 closed.
Transferred: sent 2744, received 2384 bytes, in 158.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17.3, received 15.1
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer the question. In all likelihood, you're hitting some sort of timeout. Try looking at the sshd logs on c02.

Comment: @JesseKeilson Thank you for comment. How to see the sshd logs on c02?

Comment: Depends on your sshd configuration. Probably /var/log or /var/log/secure, but could be anywhere.

Comment: @JesseKeilson I can't find it. Is there aother way?

Comment: This might also be a network device in between deciding that an idle connection should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SSH keep alive. 
On c01 create or add the following to ~/.ssh/config

```
host c02
  ServerAliveCountMax 30
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  TCPKeepAlive yes
```

This will keep send a TCP keepalive message every 60 seconds for 30 minutes. 
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5

Make sure to set the permissions as below:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

These options can also be put on the command line, but I find a config file makes things easier. If you want to apply them to every host then instead of `host c02`, use `host *`. Since there is probably a shared file system, this will work on all your ssh connections.

Note: These options could be disabled in `sshd_config`, if it is then they won't work.

Another option that might work is run an interactive command like: `watch ls ~`

Comment: I tried to edit ~/.ssh/config. Not working. where is sshd_config? I look into /etc/ssh/ssh_config, I don't know which option cause the disconnection.

Comment: You will have to be an administrator on the machine to edit sshd_config. It is typically in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. You may or may not have permission to view that file. I added a note about permissions to my answer, ssh is very picky, that might help.

Comment: Thank you. But I found the `sshd_config` is empty. So it should not be the problem of  `sshd_config`.

Comment: Are you an admin(do you have sudo/root) on c02?

Comment: No, I don't have an admin. I also tried `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval 60`. still failed.